# Backbone sub views definition - main view vs router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

Here is how my Backbone Router looks like

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "backbone"
], function ($, _, Backbone) {

    return Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "overview": "overview"
        },

        overview: function () {
            require([
                "views/overview",
                "models/user-collection",
                "grid",
                "spreadsheet"
            ], function (OverviewView, TestCollection, GridView, SpreadSheetView) {
                // Data
                var collection = new TestCollection();

                // Main view
                var view = new OverviewView({
                    el: "#page",
                    collection: collection
                });

                // Sub view #1
                var gridView = new GridView({
                    el: "#backgridWrapper"
                });

                // Sub View #2
                var spreadsheetView = new SpreadSheetView({
                    el: "#handsontableWrapper"
                });

                // Flow
                collection.fetch({
                    success: function () {
                        view.render();
                        gridView.render();
                        spreadsheetView.render();
                    }
                });

            });
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see there are several views:

1. Main view
2. Sub view #1
3. Sub view #2

I've did a lot of searching on how to organize the views and sub-views in Backbone, however all of them supposed to create a new sub-view instance directly within a view definition, so that router only knows about Main view...

So the question is - is it a good idea to handle sub-views at a router, instead of directly at view constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router should be just handling routes and initializing stuff.

Things like fetching data should go in the view that uses it - The view displays the data or error messages (in case of a failure), so I think it's wise to let the view fetch the data rather than some router who's only interested in the routes and have no interest in the data.

and I prefer initializing the **sub** views, inside their **parent** view, rather than somewhere else. The *parent - child* relationship itself justifies that, you better keep the children with their parents than a stranger so they will be under better control and you can easily find them later as well :)

Mostly it's a matter of opinion, but the thing is if you don't, all your code will soon get cluttered in the router rather than being well organized.

Below is how I'll structure the same thing.

Note that I'm initializing child views as part of parent views render method. It could be done when the parent view is initialized, but I see no point in doing so unless the parent view successfully fetches data and is proceeding to render itself.

```
define([
  "jquery",
  "underscore",
  "backbone"
], function($, _, Backbone) {

  return Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "overview": "overview"
    },
    overview: function() {
      require(["views/overview"], function(OverviewView) {
        // initialize Main view
        var view = new OverviewView({
          el: "#page"
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

define([
  "jquery",
  "underscore",
  "backbone",
  "models/user-collection",
  "grid",
  "spreadsheet"
], function($, _, Backbone, TestCollection, GridView, SpreadSheetView) {

  return Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
      this.collection = new TestCollection();
      this.fetchData();
    },
    events: {},
    render: function() {
      // rendering subviews is part of rendering their parent view.
      //I prefer to do that here

      // Sub view #1
      this.gridView = new GridView({
        el: "#backgridWrapper"
      });
      // Sub View #2
      this.spreadsheetView = new SpreadSheetView({
        el: "#handsontableWrapper"
      });
     //Below lines can be handled while initializing the respective view 
     // (In their initialize() method, or after fetching some data etc
     // or can be chained with the above initialization if their render() method returns a reference to itself (`return this`)
      this.gridView.render();
      this.spreadsheetView.render();
    },
    fetchData: function() {
      var view = this;
      this.collection.fetch({
        success: function() {
          view.render();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

*side note* : I strongly suggest not to put a collection under `models` folder.

Comment: Thank for valid point. I see you are fetching data inside a view... however it seems we are loosing an ability to cache some things (it may be done in router in my original post) if different views/routes are referring to same data. How would you solve it?

Comment: Well those views sharing same data will be sub views of a parent view who fetches the data for them.

Comment: In terms of one single route/function - yes you are right. What I'm trying to do - is think about some future issues which I may have, and there are probably use cases when different routes are referring the same data, and if we are fetching data inside a view - there is no chance to handle caching easy...

Comment: @Vytalyi please ask your question providing examples to such scenarios and ask specific questions when you hit a wall in the *future*. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Questions like this doesn't have a specific answer because you need solutions for all the problems you might encounter while building  an entire application.It's my bad turning this into an answer from a comment,  There are solutions to the scenario you mentioned above, but its not worth my time. Maybe in *future* if you put a big bounty on it I might notice it. Good like with your application.

Comment: Asking "is it a good idea?" I was referring to future issues, so its exactly Q&A format. Anyway I got you idea and it definitely make sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Vytalyi ah.. you don't understand the way site works... please read [ask].. There is an option to close questions whose answer might require content equal to a tutorial or book, and another one for closing opinionated questions... ideally you should ask a specific programming problem,  answer for "is it a good idea?" will be just "yes" or "no" :)